# CartThrob checkout_form outputting wrong return value

Tags: cartthrob

This is my template code:

```
{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form
    error_handling="inline"
    required="card_type|credit_card_number|CVV2|expiration_month|expiration_year";  
    return="store/thank-you"
    authorized_redirect="cart/authorized"
    failed_redirect="cart/failed"
    declined_redirect="cart/declined"
}

<label>Testing form return</label>

{/exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}
```

This is the HTML output:

```
<form action="http://local.729beauty.com:8888/store/payment" method="post" id="checkout_form">
<div class="hiddenFields">
<input type="hidden" value="35" name="ACT">
<input type="hidden" value="http://local.729beauty.com:8888/store/payment" name="RET">
<input type="hidden" value="store/payment" name="URI">
<input type="hidden" value="25a5d098274dc3160f8523810faa9984" name="FRM">
<input type="hidden" value="inline" name="error_handling">
<input type="hidden" value="store/thank-you" name="return">
<input type="hidden" value="cart/authorized" name="authorized_redirect">
<input type="hidden" value="cart/failed" name="failed_redirect">
<input type="hidden" value="cart/declined" name="declined_redirect">
<input type="hidden" value="fhXgN84OH//7He+A4cXWnIz6lkOXlLpUertRTQuYJk9YoLaeB8gd0mFhm3KQ4xVV8iyq/WazuYN1+AO0KgMgjw==" name="AUP">
<input type="hidden" value="aMvc2dbOlMHq47x3DAetF0q8+dJgiJnc5jrQsbCok5bZFvQeDw+8fvt+f+D6okrn3XV1W13pKBGUfzk6HBx4pg==" name="AUS">
<input type="hidden" value="hm4P2Y45BfyKYFIfMctshTwj3XIK/YZTY+1SFIraj7MRXv+1mV0Cn2fXmE94ucJVlhjB342tbHStUdElrI0ofg==" name="OTF">
<input type="hidden" value="clUmg1Fh9OCt57mfBxpB2HZHhIFYx9+a55KP9LyESvVqX8kImrEyzIvRjSBsgqaMkjANz/W0LSJIH9Jzc+T9qQ==" name="LIC">
<input type="hidden" value="fpbNvFH23jf9kBAB/2uKUN0ZrABtC+gr56EyWPf90sn+zQ+WfswMD/pX+4YhRKZNNvf1SWHGRpf24C5Kj4Cl2Q==" name="VLT">
<input type="hidden" value="0fLMF9faQwPbNeSll2SEquZQ4cGiRFFERDmWW5b8TsARIEpqD/hGOPGu+6WrvhpJPGB6/7rqXqPZaw3tkHMmjA==" name="FPR">
<input type="hidden" value="8mwr+A6qu1YL2KqV+eLw+il5yAOJVnw/0/P7ydcc5AGuvAMmN0HIpAaIkDrzkiAum1FARjINlwQEBu9hdMUp2w==" name="SM">
<input type="hidden" value="+t4T56oqmiDwn1o8KwocJ5Jx9AP4aWvWR9oJII4gGBldRTK/oagDRV275nxNZN6bZvd2Y13qSYhTbVnkQjEz3g==" name="SUB">
<input type="hidden" value="19LPDjYtW4qwaVHxrR3JpFHD6WWVqtOgPKSXnpBQyM8UtCej6XppTjxBBX3w0/4gzJQGXXZaCBEi+zuolcwkEw==" name="ERR">
<input type="hidden" value="kHX0W/xf6ylW9S8tejEOu+P0VXsIwvOxt4NAT3ov7DzOXGlyqkrLUO7hrZZ95W8uH3JTEm9guHBVRf1uSsbUJtK0+7p3puGrSGMpyfkiNejqDO6GgN9bUe/4FipX6grvKwsaSrnBgg64Bqhmclyc2Bgm48fKTrlqbNcRtdsg6re8hSHGYRVhPNr1dm+VLGhzNqy797q6K8Yv1emgJl8F8Qke8j4KQEUuAOGRWrPYbiIsC/n+7uOczQ7bjRRTmoPqSqvfo7Hlsvc8DGI5iUbDgFG7YvvnM2fg9njk6d+e5gU=" name="RLS">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="site_id">
<input type="hidden" value="91ac855ea139e6cf936f80345b0c88bbd8c2fe4e" name="csrf_token">
</div>
```

The form's action is set to something different than my return value. Any thoughts on why?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's supposed to be like that. The form will post to the page it is on and then redirect as appropriate depending on the result of the transaction. The return values are stored in the hidden fields and your successful return value is located in the 6th field down.